# How to connect to a MongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, mongodb-replica-set

I setup a cluster on aws that looks like this

```
- mycluster
--- shard0
----- node0 : P
----- node1 : S
----- node2 : S
--- shard1
----- node0: P
----- node1: S
----- node2: S
--- shard2
----- node0: P
----- node1: S
----- node2: S
```

I want to connect to it via a connection string URI.

My connection string currently look like this:

```
mongodb://host0:portX,...,host9:portZ/test-database?replicaSet=mycluster
```

but for some reason I get the error *not reachable* when I attempt to connect with it.

However, I can connect to a single shard just fine.

```
mongodb://host0:portX,...,host3:portZ/test-database?replicaSet=shard0
```

What am I missing here that is preventing me from connecting to the whole cluster?

Answer (score 5):

In a shard you connect to the shard router, i.e. the mongos process.  You don't connect to every individual shard.  Only mongos does that.

Comment: I would like to add that it can wreak havoc on data consistency when connecting to shards directly.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I didn't even realise you could connect to one from the client.

Comment: You can, since each shard is unaware that it is a shard. It is a standalone or replset from its own perspective. Now imagine you mix up the key ranges...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Odd that replica set members know that they are a replica set member, but shards don't.  The more you know...

Comment: Think of it. A replica set member has to be aware that it is part of a replset in order for voting and health checks. But it does not have to know that it is part of a sharded cluster in order to hold data. Which makes the sharding logic indefinitely less complex.

Comment: Aye, I can see why.  I had assumed purely on the basis that only a mongos should connect to it.  That being said, there might well be (and probably are) ledgitimate admin reasons to connect to a shard.

Comment: Of course there are. Adding replica set members, for example.

Comment: What happen if the server which host the "mongos" goes down? Is it better to setup a mongos on each server, so we have 3 mongos?

Comment: @ElTero Aye, there's a high level discussion [here](https://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/08/09/sharding-and-replica-sets-illustrated/)

Comment: @BanksySan assume one replicaSet has the data then you connect to the mongos, all my queries fail

Comment: @ElTero I'm afraid I don't know what else to suggest.